# How to insert all array elements in one field in SQL Server?

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server, database, insert

I have a column named "RecordIds". I am importing data from json to sql server . I have this json file. but when i inserted all in table but in last three fields i got no value in database table. how can i solve this problem ?

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "ImageName": "person1",
  "PersonName": "C1-C4:stretch",
  "GroupId": 1,
  "Text": "Sam has complete C4 tetraplegia. He sits in his power wheelchair all day and is unable to move his arms.<br/><br/>The aim of Sam`s programme is to prevent contracture.<br/><br/>This programme is suitable for people with C1-C4 tetraplegia.",
  "RecordIds": [511, 517, 569, 571, 688, 1037],
  "DropdownIds": [1, 56, 58],
  "TextTitleIds": [3, 5, 7]
}
```

here is my query

```
declare @details varchar(max)

select @details = 
BulkColumn
from openrowset(BULK'D:\JSON\mmh\examples.json', single_blob) json

if(ISJSON(@details) = 1)
  begin
    print 'Valid Json'
    insert into [dbo].[Examples]
    select * from
    openjson(@details, '$.example')
    with(
        id                      smallint        '$.Id',
        [ImageName]             varchar(50)     '$.ImageName',
        [PersonName]            varchar(50)     '$.PersonName',
        [GroupId]               smallint        '$.GroupId',
        [Text]                  varchar(50)     '$.Text',
        [RecordIds]             varchar(50)     '$.RecordIds',
        [DropdownIds]           varchar(50)     '$.DropdownIds',
        [TextTitleIds]          varchar(50)     '$.TextTitleIds'

    )

 end
else
begin
    print 'invalid Json'
end
```

i got this output

```
RecordIds            DropdownIds               TextTitleIds
NULL                  NULL                         NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [AS JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), eg

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) = 
'{
"example":
  {
      "Id": 1,
      "ImageName": "person1",
      "PersonName": "C1-C4:stretch",
      "GroupId": 1,
      "Text": "Sam has complete C4 tetraplegia. He sits in his power wheelchair all day and is unable to move his arms.<br/><br/>The aim of Sam`s programme is to prevent contracture.<br/><br/>This programme is suitable for people with C1-C4 tetraplegia.",
      "RecordIds": [511, 517, 569, 571, 688, 1037],
      "DropdownIds": [1, 56, 58],
      "TextTitleIds": [3, 5, 7]
  }
}'

  select * from
    openjson(@json, '$.example')
    with(
        id                      smallint        '$.Id',
        [ImageName]             varchar(50)     '$.ImageName',
        [PersonName]            varchar(50)     '$.PersonName',
        [GroupId]               smallint        '$.GroupId',
        [Text]                  varchar(50)     '$.Text',
        [RecordIds]             nvarchar(MAX)   '$.RecordIds' as json,
        [DropdownIds]           nvarchar(MAX)   '$.DropdownIds' as json,
        [TextTitleIds]          nvarchar(MAX)   '$.TextTitleIds' as json

    )
```

Comment: your code is working for showing but when i try to insert in table with this "insert into [dbo].[Examples]
  select * from
    openjson(@json, '$.example')
    with"

this give me error "String or binary data would be truncated in table 'myDb.dbo.Examples', column 'RecordIds'. Truncated value: '[3, 313, 426, 444, 451, 471, 479, 510, 517, 570, 5'.
"

Comment: That error means exactly what it says.  The target column is not long enough to hold the value you are trying to insert.